# С# Unity Перебор клонов в поисках пребафа

Tags: c#, unity3d, clone

прошу не выяснять что да как просто кто знает ответить.

Опишу микро эпилог чтоб было понятно.
Есть list в него заносятся по Instantiate клоны от одного пребафа. но когда я перебираю лист сравнивая с этим пребафом, он показывает что это разные объекты.

TAG, и по name не интересно.

Comment: Вот у вас рождаются дети. Как вы думаете, вы и ваш ребёнок - это один и тот же объект?

Comment: "TAG, и по name не интересно" --- а что интересно? Что вообще нужно-то? Задача-то какая?

Comment: Покажите ваш код для начала.

Comment: "Вот у вас рождаются дети. Как вы думаете, вы и ваш ребёнок - это один и тот же объект?"
ДНК же схоже на +95 процентов или я не прав?

Я же говорю найти созданный клон пребафа по пребафу.

Comment: Схожи !== ОдинИТотЖе. Судя из вопроса "показывает что это разные объекты" --- именно так это и трактуется.

Comment: В целом, вопрос ваш не ясен. Что вы делаете, что вы хотите получить, почему TAG, и по name не интересно, какая степень схожести интересна?  Почему именно "схожесть", а не поиск конкретного объекта в списке не зависимо от самого префаба? Почему так впёрся этот самый оригинал префаба? И т.д.

Comment: Ну а без кода, при такой вот формулировке это совсем 0 ясности

Answer (score -1, accepted):

По мне, так всё просто.

При инстанциировании давать объекту какой-либо его id, name внутри скрипта (в Monobehaviour). Банально `id = List.Count + 1`

И при инстанциировании нового объекта складывать либо в словарь `<int, GameObject>`, где int - это только что назначенный id, чтобы потом достать объект тупо по его id. Либо класть в список и потом через перебор списка найти объект, у которого id = искомому.

Какие-то там сравнения с исходным префабом и всякие поиски объектов по тегам не вижу никакого смысла

---

```
clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation);
clone.id = 666;
```

И всё. И дальше кладётся клон в словарь ищется по id, или в список и ищется по id объекта

Comment: Создал в классе Enum расписал типы. И сделал перебор клонов по типу.